# Returning KeyValuePair from a Linq Compiled Query

Tags: c#, linq, compiled-query, keyvaluepair

I'm just getting to grips with Compiled Queries in Linq, and have come across some strange behaviour.

This query compiles fine:

```
public static Func<DataContext, string, object> GetJourneyByUrl =
    CompiledQuery.Compile<DataContext, string, object>((DataContext dc, string urlSlug) =>
        from j in dc.Journeys
        where !j.Deleted
        where j.URLSlug.Equals(urlSlug)
        select new KeyValuePair<string, int>(j.URLSlug, j.JourneyId)
    );
```

But when I try and change the return type from object to a KeyValuePair like so:

```
public static Func<DataContext, string, KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetJourneyByUrl =
    CompiledQuery.Compile<DataContext, string, KeyValuePair<string, int>>((DataContext dc, string urlSlug) =>
        from j in dc.Journeys
        where !j.Deleted
        where j.URLSlug.Equals(urlSlug)
        select new KeyValuePair<string, int>(j.URLSlug, j.JourneyId)
    );
```

I get the following error:

> CS1662: Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type
>   'System.Func<DataContext,string,System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,int>>'
>   because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly
>   convertible to the delegate return type

How can I return a single `KeyValuePair` from a compiled query? Or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiled query will return a set of values, so in order to get it working, try changing the return type to `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` - you are returning a set of values, not just one single value. You might then want to change the function name for the compiled query to `GetJourneysByUrl`.

Then to get a single value from the result set (implied by the function name of `GetJourneyByUrl`) then you should add a function to return the first item returned by the compiled query.

```
public static KeyValuePair<string, int> GetJourneyByUrl(DataContext dc, string urlSlug) {
  return GetJourneysByUrl(dc, urlSlug).First();
}
```

You can also set this up as a `Func`, as shown on this [msdn page related to compiled queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx).

Comment: then use .First() or .Single (or similar methods) to get the value you need

Comment: spot on! instead of creating another wrapper method, i wrapped my initial query (in my Func) in (), then used first or default. thanks!